# Data not grouping correctly with datetime

Tags: python, datetime, pandas-groupby, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import fxcmpy
import numpy as np
symbols = con.get_instruments()

ticker = 'NGAS'
start = datetime.datetime(2015,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime.today()
data = con.get_candles(ticker, period='m1', number=10000)
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d %hh:%mm %s')
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d %hh:%mm %s')
data['hour'] = data.index.hour
data['minute'] = data.index.minute
```

`data` produces the following :

```
    bidopen bidclose    bidhigh bidlow  askopen askclose    askhigh asklow  tickqty hour    minute
date                                            
2019-12-05 07:00:00 2.4230  2.4280  2.4300  2.422   2.4305  2.4360  2.439   2.4295  47  7   0
2019-12-05 07:01:00 2.4280  2.4265  2.4270  2.426   2.4360  2.4340  2.436   2.4340  10  7   1
2019-12-05 07:02:00 2.4265  2.4295  2.4300  2.426   2.4340  2.4370  2.438   2.4340  35  7   2
2019-12-05 07:03:00 2.4295  2.4285  2.4300  2.428   2.4370  2.4360  2.438   2.4360  20  7   3
2019-12-05 07:04:00 2.4285  2.4350  2.4360  2.428   2.4360  2.4425  2.444   2.4360  50  7   4
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2019-12-17 15:07:00 2.3335  2.3340  2.3345  2.332   2.3410  2.3415  2.342   2.3395  94  15  7
2019-12-17 15:08:00 2.3340  2.3345  2.3355  2.334   2.3415  2.3420  2.344   2.3415  22  15  8
2019-12-17 15:09:00 2.3345  2.3335  2.3345  2.332   2.3420  2.3410  2.342   2.3410  15  15  9
2019-12-17 15:10:00 2.3335  2.3325  2.3345  2.331   2.3410  2.3400  2.342   2.3390  72  15  10
2019-12-17 15:11:00 2.3325  2.3270  2.3325  2.326   2.3400  2.3345  2.340   2.3335  99  15  11
```

In the table above hours start from 7 end end in 15. However when i run the following code, hour starts from 0 and ends at 59. Why is that?

```
df = data.groupby(['hour', 'minute']).mean()

        bidopen bidclose    bidhigh bidlow  askopen askclose    askhigh asklow  tickqty
hour    minute                                  
0   0   2.302786    2.303500    2.304286    2.302071    2.310571    2.311214    2.312000    2.310143    16.285714
1   2.294917    2.294333    2.295250    2.293583    2.302667    2.302000    2.303333    2.301333    14.500000
2   2.283000    2.283333    2.283833    2.282333    2.290667    2.290833    2.292000    2.290167    18.666667
3   2.298417    2.298833    2.299167    2.297833    2.305917    2.306333    2.307000    2.305917    14.833333
4   2.283583    2.284000    2.284250    2.283000    2.291083    2.291750    2.292167    2.291083    14.166667
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
23  55  2.285500    2.285800    2.286600    2.284700    2.293100    2.293400    2.294300    2.292600    10.400000
56  2.303800    2.304000    2.304600    2.303300    2.311400    2.311700    2.312500    2.311000    11.200000
57  2.268700    2.268400    2.268900    2.268100    2.276200    2.276100    2.276700    2.275900    5.800000
58  2.302857    2.303000    2.303286    2.302357    2.310571    2.310571    2.311214    2.310286    8.000000
59  2.321300    2.321000    2.321700    2.320400    2.328900    2.328900    2.329500    2.328700    8.400000
```

What i am trying to do is group data by hour which starts from 7 and ends at 15, then i want the mean() of that. So mean() of all the hour 7 to hour 15.

--
Edit 1:
How can i set hour and day as index?

```
data.set_index('minute', inplace = True)
data.set_index('hour', inplace = True)
```

gives me an error

Comment: why are you grouping by hour and minute?

Comment: Just a thought perhaps it is because the index is not set: `data.set_index('minute', inplace= True)` and `data.set_index('hour', inplace= True)`

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox I tried that but i got `KeyError: "None of ['minute'] are in the columns"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps `data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d %hh:%mm %s')` should be changed to `data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %S')` For hour, min and seconds!

Answer (score 3):

The results you are seeing are correct:

The date of the first line is the 5th of December, the date of the last line is the 17th December, and so there are many lines in between where the hour of the day is after 3pm or before 7am.

Try `df[df['hour']>15].head()` to see some of the lines which are later in the day than 3pm

### updated:

to get the mean for the hours 7 - 15 first see the below example code

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['hour']=np.array([15,12,10,6,4,19,15,12,10])
df['price']=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

df[(df['hour']>=7)&(df['hour']<=15)].mean().price
```

which returns

```
5.0
```

or for mean by hour

```
df[(df['hour']>=7)&(df['hour']<=15)].groupby('hour').mean()
```

which returns

```
    price
hour    
10  6
12  5
15  4
```

Comment: So how do i mean() of all the hour 7 to hour 15

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what you're seeing is a multi-index.  You're seeing hours ranging from 0 to 23 and minutes ranging from 0 to 59.

If you'd like the mean for each hour, you simply need:

`data.groupby(['hour']).mean()`.

If you do choose to group by an additional quantity such as in `data.groupby(['hour','minute']).mean()` it may be helpful to call a `.reset_index()` to avoid the confusion of the multi-index.

(e.g. `df = data.groupby(['hour','minute']).mean().reset_index()`)

Comment: I tried as you as you suggested but `df` is still goes from 0 to 23 on hour and 0 to 59 for minute.

Comment: I'm assuming you're only seeing a small fraction of the total number of dataframe rows when you printed above.  For example, if you're interested in seeing all the unique hours represented in your data, you could type ```print(data[hours].unique())```.

Comment: I am trying to set hour and minute as index but i get the error `KeyError: "None of ['minute'] are in the columns"`. I think i need to set them as index. I used `data.set_index('minute', inplace=True)
data.set_index('hour', inplace = True)`

Answer (score 2):

`%hh:%mm %s` isn't supported in python datetime, instead of:

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d %hh:%mm %s')
```

Use:

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data.index, format ='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %S')
```